# ruby on rails: any change to custom.css.scss make the app crash

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm learning rails. I have this problem and I hope you can help me.
HTTP answer code is 500 ... I am learning from a rails tutorial...
**Site crashes after adding the style - /* sidebar */**

This is my custome.css.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap";

/* mixins, variables, etc. */

$grayMediumLight: #eaeaea;

/* universal */

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  h1 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

/* typography */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: $grayLight;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}


/* header */

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

/* footer */

footer {
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid $grayMediumLight;
  color: $grayLight;
  a {
    color: $gray;
    &:hover {
      color: $grayDarker;
    }
  }
  small {
    float: left;
  }
  ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    li {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
  }
}

/* sidebar */

aside {
  section {
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid $grayLighter;
    &:first-child {
      border: 0;
      padding-top: 0;
    }
    span {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      line-height: 1;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 1.4em;
      text-align: left;
      letter-spacing: -1px;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
  }
}

.gravatar {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

**and why the site falls due to renaming the comments? it the syntax language "SASS"?**
other files https://gist.github.com/phantomass/7356307

Comment: in your project, when you type `gem list`, do you see a `sass-rails`? If not then open up your Gemfile and add `gem sass-rails` then do a `bundle install`

Comment: Yes. There is a `gem` is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here may be the way you are using [SASS comments](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#comments) and are having an issue with the compiled code.

I am not sure of your rails setup but I would take a look at the [Rails asset preprocessing section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing)

If you provide more information on your rails app I will try my best to resolve the issue.

Comment: I use rails 4... if I'm not mistaken, I have two concurrent requests. Could this be the cause of the error?

`Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (34.1ms)`
`Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (34.1ms)`
`Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1416ms`
`Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1416ms`

Comment: yes that could totally be an issue. Possibly the issue is more deep rooted than just a sass compile error.

Comment: I understand why the 2 requests (`rails_12factor` - production was not), but the solution did not help.

Comment: All the problems were due to the `gem bootstrap` version. I had a third version of the `gem`. Changing for the second version, it worked.